# Scroll Wheel event capture in a Catalyst-converted Mac app

Tags: macos, mac-catalyst

When working with a Mac app which was converted from iOS using Catalyst, the usual ways to capture a mouse's scroll wheel activity for Mac such as with

- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event;

do not work as NSEvent apparently is not supported when building a Catalyst converted app.

The object I need to control is in a regular image container and not in a scroll view container.  I am simply trying to use the scroll wheel to change the loaded image.  Trackpad activity works fine but capturing the scroll wheel so far has been elusive.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a UIPanGestureRecognizer with allowedScrollTypesMask set to UIScrollTypeMaskDiscrete:

```
    // pan gesture to recognize mouse-wheel scrolling (zoom)
    UIPanGestureRecognizer * scrollWheelGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleScrollWheelGesture:)];
    scrollWheelGesture.allowedScrollTypesMask = UIScrollTypeMaskDiscrete;   // only accept scroll-wheel, not track-pad
    scrollWheelGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 0;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:scrollWheelGesture];
```

and then

```
- (void)handleScrollWheelGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
    CGPoint delta = [pan translationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat zoom = (1000 + delta.y) / 1000;
    [self adjustZoomBy:zoom];
}
```

Comment: Normal scroll view I am able to scroll  & ZOOM  with the trackpad but with a mouse I am not able to zoom. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I was implement this code in ViewController.m and fail capture any mouse wheel event. Is there something miss ?

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5:**

```
func setupScrollWheel() {
    let scrollWheelGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(scrollWheelGestureRecognizer(_:)))
    scrollWheelGesture.allowedScrollTypesMask = .discrete
    scrollWheelGesture.maximumNumberOfTouches = 0
    view.addGestureRecognizer(scrollWheelGesture)
}

@objc func scrollWheelGestureRecognizer(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let delta = recognizer.translation(in: view)      
}
```