# How to get hardware mouse scroll wheel event data from UIPanGestureRecognizer on iOS?

Tags: ios, mousewheel

To handle hardware trackpad and mouse events in iOS, Apple added a `allowedScrollTypesMask` member to `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Their [WWDC 2020 video explaining the topic](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10094/) is pretty clear that one simply has to create and add a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` with the appropriate mask, but no real explanation about how to get any information about the scroll event itself in the handler.

I've adde the gesture handler like this:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer* panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:myView action:@selector(handlePanGesture:)];

panRecognizer.allowedScrollTypesMask = UIScrollTypeMaskDiscrete;
[myView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

and the gesture handler is correctly called twice (once for UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan and UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) with the gesture recognizer as a parameter, but the numberOfTouches is `nil` in both cases, and there doesn't seem to be a way to get any information about the scroll event (e.g. was it a scroll up, or a scroll down!?)

The documentation doesn't seem to address this at all.

Comment: [Found an answer to my own question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61630225/scroll-wheel-event-capture-in-a-catalyst-converted-mac-app).